# Can a Deadlock occur with CPU as a resource?

Tags: process, operating-system, deadlock, scheduling

I am on my fourth year of Software Engineering and we are covering the topic of Deadlocks.

The generalization goes that a Deadlock occurs when two processes A and B, use two resources X and Y and wait for the release of the other process resource before releasing theirs.

My question would be, given that the CPU is a resource in itself, is there a scenario where there could be a deadlock involving CPU as a resource?

My first thought on this problem is that you would require a system where a process cannot be released from the CPU by timed interrupts (it could just be a FCFS algorithm). You would also require no waiting queues for resources, because getting into a queue would release the resource. But then I also ask, can there be Deadlocks when there are queues?

Answer (score 1):

CPU scheduler can be implemented in any way, you can build one which used FCFS algorithm and allowed processes to decide when they should relinquish control of CPU. but these kind of implementations are neither going to be practical nor reliable since **CPU is the single most important resource an operating system has and allowing a process to take control of it in such a way that it may never be preempted will effectively make process the owner of the system** which contradicts the basic idea that ***operating system should always be in control of the system***.

As far as contemporary operating systems (Linux, Windows etc) are concerned, this will never happen because they don't allow such situations.